Expo Dev expo-camera QR scanner update to SDK 51 still not focusing
I am still facing same issue like in SDK 50 in expo-camera package. I am using expo-camera for scanning QR codes and in global it works prett well, but when someone comes with small phone or QR code is print on small paper scanner cannot focus the area like on normal camera. For example on iPhone it's called Macro mode.
I read that upgrade to SDK 51 should solve this problem as well.
Here is my settings for CameraView
<CameraView
  enableTorch={flashlight}
  style={$fullScreen}
  facing="back"
  barcodeScannerSettings={{
    barcodeTypes: ['qr'],
  }}
  onBarcodeScanned={handleBarCodeScanned}
>

Here are screenshot from normal camera

and app camera Expo Go (development mode)

is there any solution for this? I am also ok to focus on tap screen but it also doesn't work. :/

Did you solve the problem?
The documentation says to use "launchScanner()" but I can't seem to implement it.
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#scanningoptions
Thanks

Hi no I did not. I had to use other library which is called react-native-vision-camera. It solve my problem it's really great and easy to implement ;)
